# kafka.cluster.BrokerEndPoint cannot be cast to kafka.cluster.Broker

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I'm trying to stream data from kafka to spark

I'm using spark 1.6.2 with kafka 0.9.0.1 and scala 2.11.8

everything works fine when I use the receiver-based approach(KafkaUtils.createStream())
but when I try the direct approach with no receivers like this

```
val kafkaStreams = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](
  ssc,
  Map("group.id" -> "blah",
    "auto.offset.reset" -> "smallest",
    "metadata.broker.list" -> "127.0.0.1:9092",
    "bootstrap.servers"-> "127.0.0.1:9092"),
  Set("tweets")
  )
```

I get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: kafka.cluster.BrokerEndPoint cannot be cast to kafka.cluster.Broker
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$6$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:90)
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:87)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:35)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$3.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$3.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:86)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
at scala.collection.immutable.Set$Set1.foreach(Set.scala:94)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$2.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:86)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$2.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:85)
at scala.util.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:522)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster.findLeaders(KafkaCluster.scala:85)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster.getLeaderOffsets(KafkaCluster.scala:179)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster.getLeaderOffsets(KafkaCluster.scala:161)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster.getEarliestLeaderOffsets(KafkaCluster.scala:155)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$$anonfun$5.apply(KafkaUtils.scala:213)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$$anonfun$5.apply(KafkaUtils.scala:211)
at scala.util.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:522)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.getFromOffsets(KafkaUtils.scala:211)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala:484)
at SparkStreaming$.delayedEndpoint$SparkStreaming$1(SparkStreaming.scala:32)
at SparkStreaming$delayedInit$body.apply(SparkStreaming.scala:24)
at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
at SparkStreaming$.main(SparkStreaming.scala:24)
at SparkStreaming.main(SparkStreaming.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

and these are my dependencies

```
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka" % "1.6.2",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.2",
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.11" % "1.6.2",
"org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka" % "0.9.0.1"
```

I can't see where the problem is? can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Spark Streaming documentation [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#advanced-sources), Spark Streaming 1.6.2 is compatible with Kakfa 0.8.2.1.

> **Kafka:** Spark Streaming 1.6.2 is compatible with Kafka 0.8.2.1

So to solve your issue use kafka libraries of version 0.8.2.1 instead of 0.9.0.1.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I am just wondering if using 0.8.2.1 libraries with 0.9.0.1 brokers will cause any compatibility issues ?!

Comment: Kafka 0.8.2.1 libraries are compatible with Kafka 0.9.0.1 So there won't be any issues.

Comment: ok thanx again. sorry for not upvoting you answer. i don't have enough reputation yet :D

Comment: NP. My answer was helpful to you and that was real upvote :)

Comment: @avr im using spark 1.6.1 with kafka 0.9.0.0 and im getting this exception when i'm retrieving the old data from spark. At this line of code val messages  = KafkaUtils.createRDD[String, String,StringDecoder,StringDecoder](sc, kafkaConf,offsetRanges)