# Spark 2.1.0 error - kafka.cluster.BrokerEndPoint cannot be cast to kafka.cluster.Broker

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have seen several other questions on SO about this that indicate this is a dependency/version issue, e.g.
[kafka.cluster.BrokerEndPoint cannot be cast to kafka.cluster.Broker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38283598/kafka-cluster-brokerendpoint-cannot-be-cast-to-kafka-cluster-broker)

However, I can't tell what is wrong with my dependencies. I'm using Spark 2.1.0, and

```
org.apache.spark.spark-core_2.11
org.apache.spark.spark-sql_2.11
org.apache.spark.spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11
org.apache.spark.spark-streaming_2.11
```

as dependencies in my job jar I am trying to run via `spark-submit`. I know that the broker version for the Kafka server is 0.8, and these depedences are all set to 2.1.0. All of these dependencies seem compatible, so I am not sure where my error is.

**Edit:** I have discovered that if I change the `spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11` to be a provided dependency and pass it when I call `spark-submit`, it works. I am not sure why this is and why I can't just bundle it in the main jar with everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that you don't have any Kafka jars somewhere in the runtime classpath that could be getting loaded instead.

Comment: I'm not following - why would I use 1.6.3 version when I'm running Spark 2.1.0?

Comment: That is actually irrelevant since it assumes the projects are all on the same development cycle. But regardless, I thought about your problem some more and think something else is the issue.