# integration of spark 1.6.1 with kafka 0.8.2.1

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am trying to integrate spark 1.6.1 and kafka_2.10-0.8.2.1/kafka_2.10-0.9.0.1. With kafka_2.10-0.9.0.1

With DirectStream as shown below, it is failing

```
val kafkaStreams = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](
      ssc,
      Map("group.id" -> "group",
        "auto.offset.reset" -> "smallest",
        "metadata.broker.list" -> "127.0.0.1:9092",
        "bootstrap.servers"-> "127.0.0.1:9092"),
      Set("tweets")
      )
```

Getting the exception as

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: kafka.cluster.BrokerEndPoint cannot be cast to kafka.cluster.Broker
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$6$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:90)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:87)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:34)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:105)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$3.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$3.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:86)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Set$Set1.foreach(Set.scala:74)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:105)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$2.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$2.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:85)
        at scala.util.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:523)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster.findLeaders(KafkaCluster.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster.getLeaderOffsets(KafkaCluster.scala:179)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster.getLeaderOffsets(KafkaCluster.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster.getLatestLeaderOffsets(KafkaCluster.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$$anonfun$5.apply(KafkaUtils.scala:215)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$$anonfun$5.apply(KafkaUtils.scala:211)
        at scala.util.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:523)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.getFromOffsets(KafkaUtils.scala:211)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala:484)
```

I went through link "[kafka.cluster.BrokerEndPoint cannot be cast to kafka.cluster.Broker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38283598/kafka-cluster-brokerendpoint-cannot-be-cast-to-kafka-cluster-broker)" where it is mentioned that kafka 0.9 is not compatible with spark 1.6.1 and as suggested we used kafka 0.8.2.1 but we are still facing the same issue.

Environement:
  Scala -2.10.3, spark- 1.6.1, kafka (0.8/0.9)

```
    Library dependency
        "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.6.1",
        "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.10" % "1.6.1",
        "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.10" % "1.6.1",
        "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka_2.10" % "1.6.1",
        "org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka" % "0.8.0.1"  

    Please let me know if find anything inappropriate, Thanks in advance.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    I have used IO confluent which is wrapper on Kafka to resolve the issue. Confluent provides simple API and extended features to support avro cleanly. It provides Schema Registry to store multiple versions of Avro and  no need to pass avro schema from kafka producer to kafka consumer,it is handled by Confluent.
    For more clarification and features please visit https://www.confluent.io/ 
    I have used confluent 2 which is available at https://www.confluent.io/download/

Library Dependency
          libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
   "io.confluent" % "kafka-avro-serializer" % "2.0.0",
   "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.11" % "1.6.1" % "provided".
  )
 resolvers ++= Seq(
  Resolver.sonatypeRepo("public"),
  "Confluent Maven Repo" at "http://packages.confluent.io/maven/"
)

    Code sample
     val dStream:InputDStream[ConsumerRecord[String, GenericRecord]] = 
       KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, GenericRecord](
       streamingContext, PreferConsistent, Subscribe[String, GenericRecord](topics,   
       kafkaParams))

    You can iterate over dStream and do business logic.
```